# Number of possible rays in rectangular mirror room between two points

Tags: dynamical-systems, recreational-mathematics, coordinate-systems, billiards

## Question

There is a rectangular room with mirrors of $a$ width and $b$ height (Aligned with co-ordinate axes, so lower left corner is at $(0, 0)$ and upper right corner is at $(a, b)$). There are two points $A$ at $(p, q)$ and $K$ at $(x_0, y_0)$. Find the number of possible rays that start at point $A$ and reach $K$ after $0$ or more reflections.

Light ray will stop if it reaches point $A$ or $K$, so ray starting from $A$ should reach $K$ before it returns to $A$.

Also the length of ray should not exceed $d$. ($a, b, x_0, y_0, p, q, d \in \mathbb{N}$, All numbers here are natural numbers)

[Image for problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4oMA1.png)

## Attempt

I tried solving this problem by finding reflected image of point $K$.

The general co-ordinate of reflected image of point $K$ is $(2ma \pm x_0, 2nb\pm y_0)$ (here $n, m\in \mathbb{N}$)

So, the general equation of line from this image to $A$ is $\frac{y-q}{x-p} = \frac{(2nb \pm y_0)-q}{(2ma \pm x_0)-p}$

The length of array when it reaches $K$ is $\sqrt{((2nb \pm y_0)-q)^2+((2ma \pm x_0)-p)^2}$

So, we could distinguish rays using line slopes and find number of possible rays by substituting all values of $m, n$ such that distance is less than $d$.

I'm looking for a better or efficient way of solving this.

Comment: You also have to worry about the images of $A$ in case the rays from $A$ hit an image of $A$ before they hit $K$ (imagine if $p = x_0$, for example). But otherwise I think you are on the right track, in that essentially you are looking for the number of images of $d$ which are contained within a circle of radius $d$ of $A$.